# Display uploaded image in asp.net core 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

An image file is uploaded with the following code and right after the file is uploaded, I need to show it on image control. How do I do this?

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
                return Content("file not selected");
            
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",file.FileName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                string content_type = file.ContentType;
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here's my image tag:

```
<img id="picture" name="picture" width="200" height="200" src="/HomeController/RetrieveImage"></img>
```

Comment: **NB:** The `FileName` is read directly from the `Content-Disposition` header. It is completely under the control of the client. You should use `Path.GetFileName` to avoid introducing a serious security vulnerability into your code.